# Should Strunk & White be a GOLD badge on this site?

Tags: feature-request, badges

Or at least there should be a gold level badge for it.

Comment: There already is a gold level badge for it: Copy Editor.

Comment: Level aside, the badge should be called the "Chicago Manual of Style/AP Stylebook/MLA" badge instead.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think it would be far more fitting that the Strunk & White badge be given as a reward for misidentifying the passive voice. Or calling vacuous platitudes meaningful style advice. Or just for literally not knowing what you’re talking about.

[50 Years of Stupid Grammar Advice](http://chronicle.com/article/50-Years-of-Stupid-Grammar/25497)

Comment: Wow, nohat. You truly are the grammar snob snob. j/k =)

Comment: @JohnFx: You mean the "grammar snob's snob"?

Comment: @Shinto Sherlock - Are you actually correcting my grammar while I am calling nohat out for calling out someone for calling out someone else on their grammar? I think my head just exploded.

Comment: Unfortunately, the software can only register when a user edit an answer or a question; it cannot give a valuation of the edit being done.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Clearly I was being facetious. I *would* be in favor of changing the name of the badge, though.

Answer (score 1):

As the "Strunk & White" badge is given after 100 edits, it should not be a golden badge. Then, there is already a golden badge that is given after 600 edits.
I would introduce another badge for whoever makes 350 edits.

Comment: Considering when this answer has been given, I would say both are correct: The values I report are the previously used ones, and the one you report are the actually used ones.